# android google maps display bar

Tags: android, google-maps

I have attached an image of google maps running on android 2.3.5.
How do I control or create icons like in the fig.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pcmag.com](https://www3.pcmag.com/media/images/270472-google-maps.jpg))</sub>

Currently onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} will display menu from below.
What about the display bar above ,How do I edit icons above and  display the bar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls you can sse a the top of your screen is looks like an ActionBar, which was natively added since API 11.

You can try http://actionbarsherlock.com/ to implement ActionBar on any Android version.

Comment: I have tried using actionbarsherlock but how do I implement in google maps as myclass extends mapactivity and onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {} pops up the menu below ,so how do I control the action bar above. as in newclasss will have to extend sherlockactivity. Thanks Olegas for quick reply,please let me know if there  is any other way or a work around for the same.

Comment: Actionbarsherlock has a plugin to support Google maps - https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps

Comment: Thanks Olegas.I have imported library and created a demo project as in the Youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY ,Adding the googlemaps plugin by dragging the .jar file to libs folder -is that all or is there any additional configuration required. As mentioned later in the link you provided it says :-Since the Google Maps APIs are not available in central this plugin is deployed to Jake Wharton's personal repository. You can add it with the following:

<repository>
  <id>com.jakewharton</id>
  <url>http://r.jakewharton.com/maven/release</url>
</repository>

Comment: Should I add the above code? Thanks Olegas again your help would be greatly appreciated if you can help me with the gmaps actionbar plugin configuration.

Comment: To use this plugin you need to 1) Have ActionBarSherlock in your libs, 2) Have the plugin, referenced above in the libs too, 3) Select project target to Android with Google Maps API.